# Chrome 119 Dev Tools: Application > Clear site Data leaves 2GB behind

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I'm on Chrome Beta for dev purposes. In there, I was always able to scrub local site data using `Dev Tools` > `Application` > `Clear Site Data`.

Now, clicking the button leaves me with almost 3GB still showing as present in the `File System`. This does not resolve if I re-open the tab or Chrome.

I'm wondering if there's a more detailled breakdown somewhere of what Chrome considers the `File System`, and why these files are not deleted.

Since I can't find a bug filed for this anywhere, I'm thinking this is either undocumented or I'm missing something.

Any idea on how to diagnose this further?

[image: Usage: 2855MB / 587411MB quota]

Comment: Just a guess: Is the content coming from that subdomain or something else?  Many sites have files coming from secondary subdomains, google (fonts, js, etc),, cloudfront, and AWS / azure / GCP buckets for static files.  Maybe Clear Site Data is only clearing the exact subdomain?

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome. It doesn't delete File System. You'll have to do it manually or by using a utility. P.S. There's nothing unusual in having an unreported bug, there are dozens of thousands of bugs in Chrome overall and not all of them are reported, many old reports are also archived due to inactivity.

Comment: If it is a bug it wouldn't hurt to report it -- a few years ago I ran into a bug in image handling where Chromium was using a huge amount of extra memory for rendering images (which crashed a 32-bit build) and eventually got them to fix it.

Comment: Thank you all. As the day has progressed, it looks like there may be a conflict with WASM-based SQLite databases which are stored in the OPFS. I'm thinking the database locks the file, and Chrome isn't brash enough in deleting the handle while it's still open. If that IS the case, I would've expected an error from OPFS. Perhaps that's the bug I should file.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem. Can clear the File System for an app by pasting this into the console:

```
const opfsRoot = await navigator.storage.getDirectory();

opfsRoot.remove()
```